# shared_ptr.reset() not deleting

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Im starting learning about shared_ptr and weak_ptr. In theory everything looks simple. But when I started to testing, well... I have this really simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Second
{
public:
    Second()
    {
        cout << "Second created" << endl;
    }
    ~Second()
    {
        cout << "Second deleted" << endl;
    }
};

class Main
{
public:
    shared_ptr<Second> second;
    Main()
    {
        cout << "Main created" << endl;
        second = make_shared<Second>(*(new Second()));
    }
    ~Main()
    {
        second.reset();
        cout << "Main deleted" << endl;
    }
};

void fun()
{
    shared_ptr<Main> main = make_shared<Main>(*(new Main()));
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Program started" << endl;
    fun();

    cout << "Program ended" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that Second is never deleted. Here is my output:

> ```
> Program started
> Main created
> Second created
> Main deleted
> Program ended
> ```

Whats going on? I thought, that if I reset shared_ptr, and its last shared_ptr existing, object is deleting automatically.

Comment: What's this: `make_shared<Second>(*(new Second()));`? You create an object on heap, then copy it to another object. The original will never be deleted! Instead, you should do:  `make_shared<Second>();`

Comment: @DeX3r You should use the parameters of `make_shared` to initialise a class whose constructor needs parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're initializing your shared pointers wrong.  You don't need to use `new` at all when using `make_shared`.  The parameters you pass to `make_shared` are forwarded to the constructor of the class you're making.

So in your code, your `make_shared` calls should look like this:

```
shared_ptr<Main> main = make_shared<Main>();
```

and

```
shared_ptr<Second> main = make_shared<Second>();
```

Instead, what you've done is leaked a version of each class (by using new explicitly and not deleting it) and then copied the leaked value into a second version.  By splitting up the expression into multiple lines, we can more easily see what you've done wrong:

```
Second *p = new Second;
shared_ptr<Second> ss = make_shared<Second>(*p); // Calls the Second class copy constructor
// p is never deleted, so it is leaked.
```

Comment: So how come we also never see the destruction of the instance of `Second` made by `make_shared`?

Comment: I allways belived asian programmers... not anymore :P http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=V3aLw_9lBDc&t=290

Comment: @quamrana: since you did not override the copy constructor of `Main`, `second` is copied. And thus when leaking the `Main` you also leak a `shared_ptr<Second>`: by design no `delete` occurs until this reference disappears, and since you leaked it...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah! Thanks.  So `fun()` first leaks a `Main`, but since the `make_shared` there also calls the copy ctor, its member `second` is default constructed and so even though the non-leaked `Main` gets destructed, its member `second` holds nothing, so neither the call to `reset` nor the destruction of `second` calls the destructor we are looking for.

Comment: @quamrana: no... I am gonna need a schema :p

Comment: @SoapBox: No, his description is incorrect. Both instances of `Main` point to the same object, so both `Main.second` point to something (neither is null); however given the semantics of `shared_ptr` the pointed-to object is not destroyed before *both* handles are destructed... and one is leaked in the original `Main` that is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, the situation is quite complicated, so I'll need a schema.

```
class Main {
public:
    shared_ptr<Second> second;
    Main()
    {
        cout << "Main created" << endl;
        second = make_shared<Second>(*(new Second()));
    }
    ~Main()
    {
        second.reset();
        cout << "Main deleted" << endl;
    }
};

void fun()
{
    shared_ptr<Main> main = make_shared<Main>(*(new Main()));
}
```

Right after the creation of `main`, we have:

```
 <anon: Second> (leaked)

 <anon: Main>   (leaked)
             \
             |---> <Main.second: Second>
             /
 <main: Main>
```

Note that `main.second` is copied from `<anon>.second` so, as those are `shared_ptr<Second>` they both point to the same instance of `Second`.

Then, `main` dies, we are left with:

```
<anon: Second> (leaked)

<anon: Main> (leaked) ---> <Main.second: Second> (indirectly leaked)
```

Note that `second.reset()` does not necessarily destroy the pointed-to object. It simply reset the local instance of `shared_ptr`. *If* this was the last instance pointing to the object, then the object is destroyed, but otherwise... nothing.

Comment: And I also do not need that "second.reset();" in Main destructor, right? I mean it works without it but it is correct?